# Password-Generator Valid-Password Check

Tags: python, random, passwords, generator, change-password

I'm building my own Password Generator with Dictionary and Check if there is a char from every type inside. It works fine but i think i coded the check a little bit complicated.

Do you have ideas if there is a way to code this a better way.
And is there a way to break free from the check if it is allready in the lowers so it dont checks the other types?

PS: i want wo define the ussed lowers/uppers/specials/nums my self so i can allways avoid chars getting added i dont like.

```
chars = ""
alpha_lowers = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
alpha_uppers = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
specials = "$%&/()=?.,"
nums = "0123456789"
dictionary = {
    "a" : "anton",
    "b" : "berta",
    "c" : "caesar",
    "d" : "dora",
    "e" : "emil",
    "f" : "friedich",
    "g" : "gustav",
    "h" : "hotel",
    "i" : "india",
    "j" : "julia",
    "k" : "kilo",
    "l" : "ludwig",
    "m" : "marta",
    "n" : "nordpol",
    "o" : "otto",
    "p" : "paula",
    "q" : "quelle",
    "r" : "richard",
    "s" : "iegfried",
    "t" : "theodor",
    "u" : "ulrich",
    "v" : "viktor",
    "w" : "willhelm",
    "x" : "xaver",
    "y" : "ypsilon",
    "z" : "zeppelin",
    "A" : "Anton",
    "B" : "Berta",
    "C" : "Caesar",
    "D" : "Dora",
    "E" : "Emil",
    "F" : "Friedrich",
    "G" : "Golf",
    "H" : "Hotel",
    "I" : "India",
    "J" : "Julius",
    "K" : "Kilo",
    "L" : "Ludwig",
    "M" : "Marta",
    "N" : "Nordpol",
    "O" : "Otto",
    "P" : "Paula",
    "Q" : "Quelle",
    "R" : "Richard",
    "S" : "Siegfried",
    "T" : "Theodor",
    "U" : "Ulrich",
    "V" : "Viktor",
    "W" : "Willhelm",
    "X" : "Xaver",
    "Y" : "Ypsilon",
    "Z" : "Zeppelin",
    "$" : "Dollar",
    "%" : "Prozent",
    "&" : "Und",
    "/" : "Schräg",
    "(" : "Klammer auf",
    ")" : "Klammer zu",
    "=" : "Gleich",
    "?" : "Fragezeichen",
    "." : "Punkt",
    "," : "Beistrich",
    "0" : "Null",
    "1" : "Eins",
    "2" : "Zwei",
    "3" : "Drei",
    "4" : "Vier",
    "5" : "Fünf",
    "6" : "Sechs",
    "7" : "Sieben",
    "8" : "Acht",
    "9" : "Neun"
}
all_chars = True

# Kleinbuchstaben hinzufügen // Adding Lowers
chars = chars + alpha_lowers

# Großbuchstaben hinzufügen // Adding uppers
chars = chars + alpha_uppers

# Spezial-Zeichen hinzufügen // Adding Specials
chars = chars + specials

# Nummern hinzufügen // Adding Nums
chars = chars + nums

# PW-Menge definieren // How many PW
password_n = 10

# PW-Länge definieren // Password length
password_len = 32


#--------------------------------------------------------------
def password_gen(length):

    # Generating PW
    password = ""
    for i in range (0, length):
        password = password + random.choice(chars)

    # Check if there is a Char from every type    
    if all_chars == True:
        in_alpha_lowers = False
        in_alpha_uppers = False
        in_specials = False
        in_nums = False
        for c in password:
            if in_alpha_lowers == False:
                if c in alpha_lowers:
                    in_alpha_lowers = True
            if in_alpha_uppers == False:
                if c in alpha_uppers:
                    in_alpha_uppers = True
            if in_specials == False:
                if c in specials:
                    in_specials = True
            if in_nums == False:
                if c in nums:
                    in_nums = True
        if in_alpha_lowers == False or in_alpha_uppers == False or in_specials == False or in_nums == False:
            print(password + " is not valid! New Passwort will be generated!" + "\n")
            return "invalid"
        else:        
            return password
    else:
        return password

#--------------------------------------------------------------
i = 1
while i <= password_n:
    password = ""
    sentence = ""
    password = password_gen(password_len)
    
    if password != "invalid":
        print("valid Passwort")
        i += 1
        for c in password:
                sentence = sentence + " " + dictionary[c] 

        print(password)
        print(sentence.lstrip() + "\n")
```

Comment: "It works fine but i think i coded the check a little bit complicated." This is not the right place for it then. You are looking for this: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Maybe post in Code Review SE ?? There your code is reviewed and improved by the community members.

Comment: your checks are a form of "rejection sampling"; you're much better off just picking characters from the required classes then filling up the remaining length with (uniform) draws across all classes.  a final shuffle can be used to put the required classes in random locations

Answer (score -1):

*Do you have ideas if there is a way to code this a better way.*

I suggest taking look at `set`'s operation `intersect`. For example you can check if password contain lowercase letter following way:

```
alpha_lowers = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
password = "password"
haslower = bool(set(password).intersection(alpha_lowers))
print(haslower)  # True
```

Explanation: I do make set of letters common both to `alpha_lowers` and `password`, then convert it to bool, which result in `False` if that `set` is empty and `True` otherwise.

*And is there a way to break free from the check if it is allready in the lowers so it dont checks the other types?*

As you already have function you might just `return "invalid"` immediately after check was not pass.

Comment: Thanks for the operation i will take a look!

With the operation you mentioned it should work with the return i think!! ;)